How to edit and combine video clips based on CSV timestamps using Python MoviePy?
I need help automating a video editing using Python and MoviePy. I have a CSV file with series name, episode number, and start time (in seconds). My main goal is to cut each episode starting at the given timestamp. If the episode is shorter than 1 minute, the next episode should be appended until the total duration is at least 1 minute. If the episode is already longer than 1 minute I should just export that episode starting with the given start time and there is no upper duration limit.
Example CSV File:
Example Series Name,15,0.50
Example Series Name,15,1.35
Example Series Name,15,1.40
Example Series Name,16,0.24
Example Series Name,16,1.17
Example Series Name,17,0.42
The output filenames should follow this format:
[SeriesShortName][Episode][StartTime]
Expected output filenames:
ESN150050.mp4 ESN150135.mp4 ESN150140.mp4 ESN160024.mp4 ESN160117.mp4 ESN170042.mp4
I have a folder structure like this:
CSV file: Test-Info.csv
Input videos: Test-Videos
Output videos: Test-Exports
Episodes are stored in a folder called Episodes with filenames like:
1.mp4, 2.mp4, 3.mp4, and so on.
I tried to use this script but most of the time, the process starts with the wrong timestamp, and the output file name is incorrect.
For example:
If the input is Series Name,16,0.24, it starts Episode 16 at 0.13 instead of 0.24, and the output file name becomes ESN131600. (The starting timestamp isn’t exactly off by 11 seconds; that was just an example)

import csv
import os
from moviepy import * 

def correct_durations(data):
    corrected_data = {}
    for episode, times in data.items():
        corrected_data[episode] = []
        for time in times:
            minutes = int(time)
            seconds = (time - minutes) * 100
            corrected_time = minutes * 60 + seconds
            corrected_data[episode].append(corrected_time)
    return corrected_data

def generate_series_code(series_name):
    
    series_code = ''.join([word[0].upper() for word in series_name.split() if word]) 
    return series_code

def process_csv_and_create_clips(sheet_file, video_folder, output_folder):
    data = {}
    with open(sheet_file, 'r') as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        for row in reader:
            series_name, episode, start_time = row
            key = int(episode)
            if key not in data:
                data[key] = []
            data[key].append(float(start_time))

    data = correct_durations(data)

    os.makedirs(output_folder, exist_ok=True)

    for episode, start_times in sorted(data.items()):
        video_file = os.path.join(video_folder, f"{episode}.mp4")
        if not os.path.exists(video_file):
            print(f"Video file not found: {video_file}")
            continue
        
        video = VideoFileClip(video_file)
        clips = []

        for start_time in sorted(start_times):
            clip = video.subclipped(start_time, video.duration)
            clips.append(clip)

        total_duration = sum(clip.duration for clip in clips)
        if total_duration < 60:
            next_episode_file = os.path.join(video_folder, f"{episode + 1}.mp4")
            if os.path.exists(next_episode_file):
                next_video = VideoFileClip(next_episode_file)
                additional_clip = next_video.subclipped(0, next_video.duration)
                clips.append(additional_clip)

        final_clip = concatenate_videoclips(clips, method="compose")
        final_clip = final_clip.with_audio(final_clip.audio)

        series_code = generate_series_code(row[0]) 
        start_time_first_clip = int(start_times[0] * 100)
        output_name = f"{series_code}{episode:02d}{start_time_first_clip:04d}.mp4"
        output_path = os.path.join(output_folder, output_name)
        final_clip.write_videofile(output_path, codec="libx264", audio_codec="aac")

        video.close()
        for clip in clips:
            clip.close()



sheet_file = "/Test-Info.csv"
video_folder = "/Test-Videos"
output_folder = "/Test-Export"

process_csv_and_create_clips(sheet_file, video_folder, output_folder)

